# Selenium Python nested dropdowns

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm trying to test a nested dropdown with Selenium Python using the conditional statements like so:
[image]

```
if d_Biz == 'Marketing':
                biz_choose = driver.find_element("xpath", "//span[@id='biz']")
                biz_choose.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='Marketing']").click()
                time.sleep(1)

                if d_Subbiz_1 == 'GMV':
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='GMV']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_2) + "']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)

                elif d_Subbiz_1 == 'CLM':
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='CLM']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_2) + "']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)

                else:
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_1) + "']").click()

            elif d_Biz == 'Lzdpay':
                biz_choose = driver.find_element("xpath", "//span[@id='biz']")
                biz_choose.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='Lzdpay']").click()

                if d_Subbiz_1 == 'Wallet':
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='Wallet']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_2) + "']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)

                elif d_Subbiz_1 == 'BAR':
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='BAR']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_2) + "']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)

            else:
                biz_choose = driver.find_element("xpath", "//span[@id='biz']")
                biz_choose.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@data-tag='gateway-wrapper']")
                gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Biz) + "']").click()
```

As you can see, I'm writing it 1 by 1. It works fine but then when the data is

```
Biz: Marketing
Sub Biz 1: Engagement
Sub Biz 2: Engagement
```

or

```
Biz: Marketing
Sub Biz 1: Branding
Sub Biz 2: Branding
```

it gives an error saying :

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element <span data-meta="Field" id="purpose" class="next-select large voucher-template-input" tabindex="0">...</span> is not clickable at point (526, 335). Other element would receive the click: 
<li class="next-cascader-menu-item">...</li>
```

In conclusion, this code works fine if the Sub Biz 1 and Sub Biz 2 is not the same value. Any solutions? By the way, I'm new to selenium.

[[edit]]
I also tried coding like this:

```
if d_Biz is not None:
                biz_choose = driver.find_element("xpath", "//span[@id='biz']")
                biz_choose.click()
                time.sleep(1)
                gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='next-cascader-menu-wrapper'][1]")
                gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Biz) + "']").click()
                if d_Subbiz_1 is not None:
                    gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='next-cascader-menu-wrapper'][2]")
                    gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_1) + "']").click()
                    time.sleep(1)
                    if d_Subbiz_2 is not None:
                        gwrapper = driver.find_element("xpath", "//div[@class='next-cascader-menu-wrapper'][3]")
                        gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_2) + "']").click()
                        time.sleep(1)
```

With this code, it works fine for the duplicated value for d_Subbiz_1 and d_Subbiz_2 while the error shows when there are no d_Subbiz_1 or d_Subbiz_2 value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when Sub Biz 1 and Sub Biz 2 have the same value, as you' re locating them using text, the locator works for both of them and you are pointing to first one (parent) again. try using indexes in your locators like `"(//li[normalize-space()='" + str(d_Subbiz_2) + "'])[1]"` or choose different unique locators for all the drop down list items.
I also suggest to use hashtable (dictionary) for this part. For example

```py
def choose_biz_dropdowns(d_biz = None, subbiz1 = None, subbiz2 = None):
    d_biz_dict = {'Marketing': 'XPATH', 'Customer Care': 'XPATH', 'Commercial': 'XPATH', 'People': 'XPATH', 'Other': 'XPATH', 'Lzdpay': 'XPATH'}
    d_subbiz_1_dict = {'GMV': 'XPATH', 'CLM': 'XPATH', 'Engagement': 'XPATH', 'Branding': 'XPATH', 'Partnership': 'XPATH', 'Lucky Voucher': 'XPATH'}
    d_subbiz_2_dict = {'Engagement': 'XPATH', 'UAT Test': 'XPATH',}
    if d_biz is not None:
        driver.find_element("xpath", d_biz_dict[d_biz])
    if subbiz1 is not None:
        driver.find_element("xpath", d_subbiz_1_dict[subbiz1])
    if subbiz2 is not None:
        driver.find_element("xpath", d_subbiz_2_dict[subbiz2])
```

if you want to not do the second and third drop down (for example "Customer Care"), you can simply leave the argument value as None. In case you want to continue to the last dropdown steps, you should pass all 3 elements name.

Comment: is it okay if I put def inside a def?

Comment: also tried using indexes, but it gives an error saying ```no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[normalize-space()='Marketing'][0]"}```

Comment: Try this one: `"//(li[normalize-space()='Marketing'])[1]"`. Or `"//(li[normalize-space()='Marketing'])[2]"`. Note that the indexes starta from 1, not 0. Also you should target the whole expression using  parentheses.

Comment: hi! pls check my edited question, I've tried using index and it works fine for the duplicated value of Subbiz 1 and Subbiz 2, but when one of them or both are null, it gives an error

Comment: Hi, of course it does. Because your locator strategy is based on Value. You can change the element locators by using the ID or Class instead. Anyway I'm not sure why you want to click on a null list option?!

Comment: I've found the answer by checking if the element exist or not first using ```driver.find_elements``` and then it can continue to Subbiz 1 and Subbiz 2, thank you though for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem i see is that you use 'global' selectors.
`//` Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are.

Depending on the exact html output of your dropdown, you should select the direct child "Marketing" element with

```
gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "li[normalize-space()='Marketing']")
// or:
gwrapper.find_element("xpath", "ul/li[normalize-space()='Marketing']")
```

Also see:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#find-elements-from-element